# Why is nginx serving one sub-domain over SSL?

Tags: ssl, nginx, dns

I am new to nginx. So, I know I will need to post additional info. Apologies for starting with a lack of info.

I have my first nginx server set up with virtual domains. The problem domain is a sub-domain with DNS (A record) set up on external nameservers.

When I enter the domain name I am directed to my server's IP, but, through https. The connection is refused. Here is my .conf for the domain:

```
    server {
    listen *:80;


    server_name dev.imageweaversmarketing.com ;

    root   /var/www/dev.imageweaversmarketing.com/web;



    index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

    error_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/dev.imageweaversmarketing.com/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/dev.imageweaversmarketing.com/access.log combined;

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /stats/ {

        index index.html index.php;
        auth_basic "Members Only";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/stats/.htpasswd_stats;
    }

    location ^~ /awstats-icon {
        alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /stats/ {

        index index.html index.php;
        auth_basic "Members Only";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/stats/.htpasswd_stats;
    }

    location ^~ /awstats-icon {
        alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files /cdb8ed7968b49bb25b7be537a21b99cb.htm @php;
    }

    location @php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

 }
```

Can anyone help?

**Edit**
I am now at least getting a response. However, it is a 500 error.
Here is the result of a tail on teh error.log

```
2016/05/09 21:12:35 [error] 4847#0: *24 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/error/404.html", client: 184.35.8.90, server: dev.imageweaversmarketing.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "dev.imageweaversmarketing.com", referrer: "http://dev.imageweaversmarketing.com/"
```

Comment: Did you used HSTS (the header Strict Transport Security ) in the past ?

Comment: Could you provide your ip and the name of the broken subdomain ?

Comment: @Tom I appended more info that includes the bits you requested.

Comment: The connection is refused for https because you only listen on port 80. To activate https you must listen on port 443 with the ssl option and set_up the certificates...